# Differentiation of a function $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given,

$f(x) = \sqrt{\sin x + \sqrt{\cos x +\sqrt{\sin x + \sqrt{\cos x.....}}}}$

I need to find $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$.

I have tried by squaring both sides but was not able to make any headway.

If anyone helps me, I shall be highly obliged.

Comment: Hint:

$y = \sqrt{\sin x + \sqrt{\cos x +\sqrt{\sin x + \sqrt{\cos x.....}}}}$

$y= \sqrt{\sin x + \sqrt{\cos x + y}}$

Comment: [As a continuation to the previous comment, y = $\sqrt {sinx + { \sqrt{cosx +y}}}$, square both sides and differentiate]

Comment: @ビキマンダル Thank you

Comment: @User0 Thank you